# unsure why this jQuery click event is fired here

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created this snippet http://jsfiddle.net/PexkV/

```
<script>
var arc={};

arc.handler={
  background_color:'#8DBC8F',
  console_this: function(str){
    alert('lets write this to the console ' + str + ' ' + this.background_color);
  }

}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.more-click-me').on('click', arc.handler.console_this('here'));
  $('.more-click-me').on('click', function(){
    arc.handler.console_this('blue');
  });

});
</script>
<div class='more-click-me'>lets write this</div>
```

and am unsure why the first event is being called automatically (the 'here' in the example). It seems like it should only be called  in response to a click? What am I not getting? If I made some really stupid syntax issue, sorry in advance.

thx in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are calling the function and passing the return value of it to `.on()`. The easiest way to achieve what you're trying to achieve will be to pass an anonymous function to `.on()`, like you do in the 2nd example, and call your `console_this` function within it:

```
$('.more-click-me').on('click', function () {
    arc.handler.console_this('here');
});
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/PexkV/1/).

Comment: it just seems so counter-intuitive that the js interpreter would jump into the a callback and run the code. Is it safe to say that all callbacks like this should probably be wrapped in an anonymous function? sorry not full-time JS dev and adopted some code

Comment: Well if you think about, when you bind the event handler, you pass a reference to a function as a callback. That third argument will always be evaluated and whatever it returns will be passed through as that callback, so you need to pass a reference to a function (since that's what will be used to execute the function at the appropriate time). By calling the function, you're passing through the return value, rather than the reference. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

because you are calling the function

```
arc.handler.console_this('here')
```

That is not assigning the function. It should look like the second one.

```
$('.more-click-me').on('click', arc.handler.console_this('here'));  <-- wrong
$('.more-click-me').on('click', function(){  <-- right, uses a closure
    arc.handler.console_this('blue');
});
```

so it should be

```
$('.more-click-me').on('click', function(){ arc.handler.console_this('here'); });  
$('.more-click-me').on('click', function(){ arc.handler.console_this('blue'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.more-click-me').on('click', arc.handler.console_this('here'));
$('.more-click-me').on('click', function(){
    arc.handler.console_this('blue');   });
```

In the first line, you are calling the method & trying to bind the result to the event.

The second line is enough to set up the event binding.